# Link to my app that opens in mail on the iPhone, or the PC desktop

Tags: iphone, http, app-store, hyperlink

I'm trying to email someone a link to my iPhone app in the app store.

I've tried Apple's app-link-maker.

I've tried many of the suggestions here (and elsewhere) to use http: or itms: or itms-app:.

Or to use itunes.apple.com or phobos.apple.com or ax.search or several others.

I can't seem to get ***ONE*** link that works in both situations:

- 1) The user might be reading his email on his PC at home.
- 2) The user might be reading his email on his iPhone.

Various tries will always fail in either 1 of the 2 situations, when the user clicks on the link in his email.

("Can't open iTunes."  "Too many redirections."   Or it incorrectly tries to open the music-store instead of the app-store.  "Can't find that app."  Wastes time opening a browser on the iPhone, only to close it, just to open the appStore.)

Is there some magic link that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

This one is easy

Go to the app in itunes

when you are in app's description page click on the grey drop down button under the large icon

select 'copy link'

paste link into an email

Voila